# C# Absolute File Path on Linux/MacOS

Tags: c#

Consider the following code:

```cs
byte[] bytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync("~/Desktop/data.bin");
```

This throws the following error:

> Could not find a part of the path '/Users/mainuser/Desktop/DataExample/DataExample/bin/Debug/net5.0/~/Desktop/data.bin'.

Why is the path not considered absolute, and how do I fix this?

Note: I'm running this on MacOS, but the same (presumably) applies to Linux.

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried Path.GetFullPath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you can try `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)` ?